# How to convert keras model to corml format using coremltools

Tags: tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

I want to convert my keras model to coreml using coremltools.
When I try to do this, it gives me an error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'relu6'

My tensorflow version is 1.5.1
My keras version is 2.1.6

The complete colab file is here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kSeErLsp_xaU37haUrwBO5jiNlV2RCll

I have already tried different versions of the modules but I am ready to try a new version I haven't tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your installation still tries to use Keras 2.2.0, since the error in coremltools happens after it checks that the Keras version >= 2.2.0.

Write `keras.__version__` to see what version of Keras your notebook is really using.

Try installing an older version of `keras_applications`, one that still has the `relu6` function. It was recently changed. The problem with Keras is that stuff often moves around between minor versions.

Comment: How do I install a later version of keras

Comment: You have to put the `!pip install` commands into a file `setup.py` and put it in your Google Drive. Now when you run the colab notebook, it will first install the right version of Keras and then start the notebook. By doing `!pip install` inside the notebook, it doesn't see those packages until you restart the notebook.